# includeHtml doesn't do its job

Tags: copyleaks-api

So I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/plagiarism-checker/v/3.0.1 to interact with Copyleaks' API and it's working great, except for the fact that setting CopyleaksFileSubmissionModel.includeHtml to true doesn't make it send the HTML on the completion webhook.

[what my submit method looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKUdN.jpg)

```
can't add link to pastebin without a code block
```

[req.body.json](https://pastebin.com/dqR35svJ)

[report on Copyleaks website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjPwm.png)

Clicking on one of the results on the Copyleaks website does present me with the JSON containing the HTML and text for the scan.

So am I missing something or does includeHtml not work?

Answer (score 0):

> except for the fact that setting
> CopyleaksFileSubmissionModel.includeHtml to true doesn't make it send
> the HTML on the completion webhook.

It might be misunderstanding of the scan cycle. The "[Completion webhook](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/webhooks/completed)" doesn't hold information about the HTML version of the content.

The HTML version of the submitted file can be downloaded by you on the [Export](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/downloads/export) method. Take a look on the `crawledVersion` parameter:

```
{
  "crawledVersion": {
    "verb": "POST",
    "headers": [
      [
        "header-key",
        "header-value"
      ]
    ],
    "endpoint": "https://yourserver.com/export/export-id/crawled-version"
  },
  "completionWebhook": "https://yourserver.com/export/export-id/completed",
  "maxRetries": 3
}
```

After exporting the `crawledVersion` JSON to your servers, you will find there the HTML presentation of your submitted file.